# Triggering tkinter callbacks via GUI user interaction and line command

Tags: python, chess

I am modifying a nice Chess game that I found [here](https://github.com/lasoren/python-chess-ai/blob/master/GUIRunner.py).

This game is initialized this way:

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", app.callback)
root.mainloop()
```

This initialization provide a GUI with a chessboard. Every time that I move a piece, a

```
def callback(self,event)
def displayBoard(self):
```

is triggered and make all the magic (move the piece, check if is a valid move, and etc)

This is working fine. However, I would like to change this so I can also trigger this function by, for example, the command line.

Explaining in better detail, I wanna be able to move a piece of the chessboard not only by the user input via the GUI but also typing commands (e.g. move to position x,y) instead of only being able to play via GUI.

Is this a possible change or would I have to change the whole core?

Comment: some programs use built-in HTTP server or socket to receive external message - but it would need a lot of changes. The only idea is to use [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or pynput to send mouse/key event to GUI to simulate mouse moves. And then you could write command and it would move mouse and click on board - it doesn't need changes in Chess game but it would need still some work.

Comment: maybe using `root.after(milliseconds, function)` you could periodically run function which would check some file or socket or queue for information and you could use other program to put information in this file/socket/queue.

Comment: ***" move a piece"***: Simulate the `"<Button-1>"` event, call `app.callback(...` with the needed `event` values.

Comment: @stovfl , do you mean typing on, for example, the "Immediate Window" the command "move a piece"? Or do you mean some function called move a piece? (e.g. def makeMove(self,guiBoard,color):)

Comment: @FabioSoares: I assume, to *move a pice* there are at least **two** clicks required. Your command: ***move A2 to A3***  get translated into `app.callback(event.x/y=<coord of A2>)` and `app.callback(event.x/y=<coord of A3>)` which should result in the same behavior as clicking: `A2` then `A3`. If your *move pice* are using **draging** this approach will fail.